# After forcing an orientation of an IOS 7 app to Portrait, nothing on the screen becomes tappable

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, screen-orientation

I am seeing an issue that only happens on IOS 7 and not IOS 6, i.e. the same code works on 6 but not 7.

Basically, there is this view that I need to transition to that must be in portrait mode.

So, like many of the other examples I found on StackOverflow, the way to force an orientation would be to call this on the navigation controller :

```
UIViewController *mvc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

[self presentViewController:mvc animated:NO completion:^{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        NSLog(@"Cleared");
        [mvc.view removeFromSuperview];
        [mvc removeFromParentViewController];
    }];
}];
```

And in the target controller, I have:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
   return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
   return NO;
}
```

However, once I transition to this target UIViewController, nothing on that UIViewController becomes tappable at all. I am very sure that the UIButtons are linked properly because if I just load up this controller as the first controller when the app starts, the buttons all worked fine, but if I have to force an orientation on it before showing it, then the buttons don't work

I was wondering if anyone else has encountered such an issue in IOS 7 as well? This works perfectly in IOS 6

Thanks
IS

Comment: why dont you try embedding your landscape VC? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491786/force-landscape-viewcontroller-in-ios-7/22491787#22491787