# Force Landscape ViewController in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have more than ten ViewControllers in portrait mode, but I need to force a single one in Landscape mode regardless of the device´s orientation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the solution:

1) Embed the LandscapeViewController in a subclassed NavigationController and connect it from your PortraitViewController using a **modal segue.**

[image: LandscapeViewController embedded into a new LandscapeNavigationController]

2) Subclass UINavigationController

LandscapeNavigationController.m

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

3) Don't forget to dismiss your modal VC (in this case from my Bar Buttom Item Action)

```
- (IBAction)goBack:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Using categories like that is a terrible idea - its undocumented behaviour about what happens on collisions. You should always prefix methods when using categories to avoid this. Subclassing the navigation controller in this instance would be a better solution.

Comment: You are right @OliverAtkinson. I was changing my solution with your approach. Im editing my answer

Comment: The point with these categories is to override. But I'd go with a subclass.

Comment: How can I do this programmatically?

Comment: It shows in landscape mode..but on dismiss it makes my previous viewcontroller in landscape instead of showing in portrait mode....

Comment: @Tommy did you try writing in your previous VC the following:

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

??? let me know if it helps

Comment: Thank you @FedeCugliandolo..Instead of that I used separate subclassed NavigationController with portrait mode,it worked ;)..